# Add scheme to URL if needed

Tags: c#, .net, uri

To create a Uri from a string you can do this:

```
Uri u = new Uri("example.com");
```

But the problem is if the string (like the one above) doesn't contain the protocol you will get an exception: "`Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`"

To avoid the exception you should secure the string includes a protocol, like below:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://example.com");
```

But if you take the url as input, how can you add the protocol if it's missing?

I mean apart from some IndexOf/Substring manipulation?

Something elegant and fast?

Comment: `IndexOf` Should be fast enough.

Comment: Minor point; "scheme"... not "protocol"

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You could also use [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static Uri GetUri(this string s)
{
    return new UriBuilder(s).Uri;
}
```

Remarks from MSDN:

> This constructor initializes a new instance of the UriBuilder class with the Fragment, Host, Path, Port, Query, Scheme, and Uri properties set as specified in uri.
>
> **If uri does not specify a scheme, the scheme defaults to "http:".**

Comment: This says the hostname could not be parsed when you try protocall-less url's such as "//domain.com"

Comment: Use with care: Input with a port like `stackoverflow.com:80` is parsed without error, but is interpreted as `Scheme: stackoverflow.com`, `Path: 80`: `Port: -1`. Not exactly as expected ...

Comment: This works if the scheme is missing. If the hostname is missing too (e.g. `/foo/bar`), this will throw "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.".

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to add the scheme, without validating the URL, the fastest/easiest way is to use string lookups, eg:

```
string url = "mydomain.com";
if (!url.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) url = "http://" + url;
```

A better approach would be to use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to also validate the URL using the [`TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri.TryCreate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
string url = "mydomain.com";
Uri uri;
if ((Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) || Uri.TryCreate("http://" + url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) &&
    (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
{
    // Use validated URI here
}
```

As @JanDavidNarkiewicz pointed out in the comments, validating the `Scheme` is necessary to guard against invalid schemes when a port is specified without scheme, e.g. `mydomain.com:80`.

Comment: This approach will not work due to a very subtle issue: A url with a port ("mydomain.com:8080") will return true when passed to TryCreate. The scheme for the Uri is mydomain.com. The think the Uri class has a bug but that is above m pay grade.

Comment: @JanDavidNarkiewicz You're correct, this is probably because `mailto:` and `tel:` are valid schemes as well and the port delimiter is seen as scheme delimiter. I've updated the code to guard against this!

Comment: @S.Serpooshan Only if you're sure the URL supports HTTPS... So the safest way is to default to HTTP (just like browsers, editors, etc. do)!

Answer (score 4):

My solution was for protocall-less urls to make sure they have protocal was regex :

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"^\/\/", "http://");
```

Comment: this regex only test if there is a double slash `//` at beginning of string, not work for example for `www.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, although `Uri` and `UriBuilder` completely mangle any url without a scheme, `WebProxy` does it right.

So just call:

```
new WebProxy(proxy.ProxyServer).Address
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer results in http and not https. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969033/828184) and built up on it

```
namespace UrlHelper
{
    using System;

    public class UrlExtensions
    {
        public static Uri AddHttpsPrefixToString(string url)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            {
                return null;
            }

            Uri uri;
            try
            {
                uri = new UriBuilder(url) {
                    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                    Port = -1 // default port for scheme
                }.Uri;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"UrlExtensions.AddHttpsPrefixToString: Could not parse {url}");
                return null;
            }

            return uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var termsStringOrNull = UrlExtensions.AddHttpsPrefixToString("example.com")?.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

We had some specific cases where there was a legacy allowance to input stuff like:
localhost:8800 or similar. Which means we needed to parse that. We built a little more elaborate ParseUri method that separated the possibility to specify a URI very loosely, but also caught the times where people would specify a non-standard scheme (and also the host in IP-long notation, because sometimes people do that)

Just like UriBuilder it will default to the http scheme if none is specified. It will have issues if a basic authentication is specified and the password consists only of numbers. (Feel free to fix that community)

```cs
        private static Uri ParseUri(string uri)
        {

            if (uri.StartsWith("//"))
                return new Uri("http:" + uri);
            if (uri.StartsWith("://"))
                return new Uri("http" + uri);

            var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(uri, @"^([^\/]+):(\d+)(\/*)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                var port = int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);
                if (port <= 65535) //part2 is a port (65535 highest port number)
                    return new Uri("http://" + uri);
                else if (port >= 16777217) //part2 is an ip long (16777217 first ip in long notation)
                    return new UriBuilder(uri).Uri;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid port or ip long, technically could be local network hostname, but someone needs to be hit on the head for that one");
            }
            else
                return new Uri(uri);
        }
```