# Formatting a string as a URL

Tags: c#, string, format, uri

What is the correct to format a string as a URL?

i.e.
    'google.com' becomes 'http://www.google.com' and 'www.stackoverflow.com' becomes 'http://www.stackoverflow.com.'

I imagine it is something using the `Uri`class but from what I can tell, `new Uri(mystring).AbsoluteUri` doesn't 'format' the string.

Comment: FYI: You should *not* convert `website.com` to `www.website.com`; they may be two different things.

Comment: Right, thanks. This is to correct and variation in user input so that the URL will work will WebClient, HttpRequest, etc.

Comment: i believe that `http://www.google.com` is technically correct, and when you just type `google.com` into your browser the `http://www.` added when it appears as though `google.com` doesn't exist

Comment: @SamIam Your browser is adding `http://` and Google's servers themselves are returning a redirect telling the browser to request `www.google.com`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add protocol to url if needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289739/add-protocol-to-url-if-needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UriBuilder` class to construct the URL. It will add `HTTP://` as a default scheme if the string doesn't specify one.

I found this out from an answer to this question [Add scheme to URL if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289739/add-protocol-to-url-if-needed)

Answer (score 3):

`http` is a protocol and a built-in class has no way of knowing it. It could be `file` or `ftp` or any other protocol. So you should form it by yourself