# Regex Issue in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a C# routine that removes all of the following prefixes and suffixes and returns just the root word of a domain:

```
var stripChars = new List<string> { "http://", "https://", "www.", "ftp.", ".com",  ".net", ".org", ".info", ".co", ".me", ".mobi", ".us", ".biz" };
```

I do this with the following code:

```
originalDomain = stripChars.Aggregate(originalDomain, (current, repl) => Regex.Replace(current, repl, @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Which seems to work in almost all cases.  Today, however, I discovered that setting "originalDomain" to "NameCheap.com" does not return:

```
NameCheap
```

Like it should, but rather:

```
NCheap
```

Can anyone look at this and tell me what is going wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I presume its something to do with the .me .... matching ame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but given the specific task you are trying to accomplish I would recommend trying something like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(originalDomain);
originalDomain = uri.Host;
```

**EDIT:**

If your input may not contain a scheme you can use the uri builder as notied in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289739/add-protocol-to-url-if-needed)

```
var hostName = new UriBuilder(input).Host
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem I am having is that sometimes the domain has http://, sometimes ftp://, and sometimes nothing.  So I need a catch all for the stripping.  When I try using the code above, without a http://, it gives me an error "The format of the URI could not be determined".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

THis is normal: the dot in a regex means any character.

Therefore, `.me` matches `ame` in `NameCheap`.

Escape the dots with a backslash.

Also, you'd be better off using a dedicated URI API for this kind of operation.

Comment: Is this what Jay is offering below?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Java has `URI` for this. You should use that, since it will parse the URI for you and do the right thing in each scenario. All you will have to do is then work on the host part.