# CheckSchemeName fail on url with multiple prefix

Tags: c#

I have this url: `turnerstadium.co.il`, I'm trying to check if the `scheme` is correct so I did:

```
if (!Uri.CheckSchemeName(link))
{
   link = "http://" + link;
}
```

the problem is that `CheckSchemeName` return `true`, so when I do this:

```
var url = new Uri(link);
```

I get:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

how can I fix that?

Comment: Che [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968426/changing-the-scheme-of-system-uri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code of CheckSchemeName method.

```
public static bool CheckSchemeName(string schemeName)
{
  if (schemeName == null || schemeName.Length == 0 || !Uri.IsAsciiLetter(schemeName[0]))
    return false;
  for (int index = schemeName.Length - 1; index > 0; --index)
  {
    if (!Uri.IsAsciiLetterOrDigit(schemeName[index]) && schemeName[index] != '+' && (schemeName[index] != '-' && schemeName[index] != '.'))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

From the remarks section of [Uri.CheckSchemeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.checkschemename?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The scheme name must begin with a letter and must contain only
>   letters, digits, and the characters ".", "+", or "-".

So as you can see, this method only checks if the string you are passing meets these requirements.

If you only want to check if the string starts with "http://" and append it in case it is not there, one of the possible solutions would be:

```
  if (!link.StartsWith("http://"))
  {
    link = "http://" + link;
  }
```

Otherwise I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578857/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-http-url).

Answer (score -1):

Check UriBuilder at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2

It has constructors to add the scheme if the scheme is not present.

```
var url = new UriBuilder("siteUrl.com").Uri.ToString();
```

This will return "http://siteUrl.com"